# ThickBox with googlemaps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe, thickbox

I was wondering if its possible to use the Google maps IFRAME code to show up in a thickbox jQuery lightbox. Any help I am trying to use the embeded url but no luck. has anybody seen a solution to this problem I have tried googling but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the Google iframe inside a hidden div, and open it as [inline content](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#sectiond-1) with Thickbox.

```
<a href="#TB_inlinemodalContent?height=400&width=430&inlineId=modalContent" title="add a caption to title attribute / or leave blank" class="thickbox">Show hidden modal content.</a>

<div id="modalContent" style="display:none;">
    <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.09024,-95.712891&amp;spn=24.455808,37.353516&amp;z=4&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=37.09024,-95.712891&amp;spn=24.455808,37.353516&amp;z=4&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
</div>
```